# Spring: Cannot autowire beans from parent context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired, applicationcontext

I have a Spring Boot (1.4.0) application, which, during initialization, starts a 2nd context (I need that because I have to publish a web service using a specific kind of authorization while the parent context publishes a different service).

I created a child context like so:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({Servlet.class, DispatcherServlet.class})
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
public class ChildContextConfiguration implements ApplicationContextAware, ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChildContextConfiguration.class);
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    private void createChildContext() {
        final AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext childContext = new AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext(ChildConfiguration.class);
        childContext.setParent(this.applicationContext);
        childContext.setId(this.applicationContext.getId() + ":child");
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        logger.info("creating child context");
        createChildContext();
    }
}
```

The child context's configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.child"})
@PropertySource("file:some-config.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "child")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ChildConfiguration {

    private Integer port;
    private String keyStore;
    private String keyStorePass;
    private String keyPass;
    private String trustStore;
    private String trustStorePass;
    private String packageBase;

    public void setPort(Integer port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void setKeyStore(String keyStore) {
        this.keyStore = keyStore;
    }

    public void setKeyStorePass(String keyStorePass) {
        this.keyStorePass = keyStorePass;
    }

    public void setKeyPass(String keyPass) {
        this.keyPass = keyPass;
    }

    public void setTrustStore(String trustStore) {
        this.trustStore = trustStore;
    }

    public void setTrustStorePass(String trustStorePass) {
        this.trustStorePass = trustStorePass;
    }

    public void setPackageBase(String packageBase) {
        this.packageBase = packageBase;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller swpMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan(packageBase);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public Unmarshaller swpUnmarshaller() throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(packageBase);
        return jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter encodingFilter() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return encodingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerProperties serverProperties() {
        ServerProperties props = new ServerProperties();
        props.setPort(port);
        props.setSsl(ssl());

        return props;
    }

    private Ssl ssl() {
        Ssl ssl = new Ssl();
        ssl.setEnabled(true);
        ssl.setKeyStore(keyStore);
        ssl.setKeyStorePassword(keyStorePass);
        ssl.setKeyStoreType("JKS");
        ssl.setKeyPassword(keyPass);
        ssl.setTrustStore(trustStore);
        ssl.setTrustStorePassword(trustStorePass);
        ssl.setClientAuth(Ssl.ClientAuth.NEED);


        return ssl;
    }
}
```

So far, this works. But when I try to autowire a bean from the parent context, I get an error stating that there is no candidate.

Another interesting thing is, when I inject the (child)context into one of my child context's beans using the ApplicationContextAware interface, the getParent() property of that context is null at that time.

What I have done now is implementing getter functions like these:

```
private SomeBean getSomeBean() {
    if (this.someBean == null) {
        this.someBean = applicationContext.getParent().getBean(SomeBean.class);
    }
    return this.someBean;
}
```

To summarize this: During construction of the child context's beans, the parent context is not set, so I cannot use autowire.

Is there some way to make autowire work with my setup?

Answer (score 2):

Constructor taking classes to register refreshes context internally - try to set class and refresh manually after setting parent context.

```
private void createChildContext() {
    final AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext childContext = new AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext();
    childContext.setParent(this.applicationContext);
    childContext.setId(this.applicationContext.getId() + ":child");
    childContext.register(ChildConfiguration.class);
    childContext.refresh();
}
```

Comment: This is certainly a step in the right direction. Unfortunately, I was stuck in a refresh loop. The first ContextRefreshedEvent was triggered by the parent context, the following ones were coming from the child context. So I only called createChildContext() when the event is emitted by the root context. That seemed to work, but then the child context's tomcat tries to bind on the root context's port BUT using SSL (which is configured for the child, not the parent)

Comment: Update: When I comment out childContext.setParent(this.applicationContext); I only get one ContextRefreshedEvent and everythinf else works (besides accessing beans from the parent context, since there is none).

Comment: I pushed a sample project to  github: https://github.com/thomashoell/SpringBootChildContext. The interesting part resides in the class ChildContextConfig. When I set the parent context **BEFORE** calling refresh, it does not work. From what I noticed, the child context seems to use the parent context's tomcat.

Comment: What is the current problem? - your sample passes the single test is has and runs successfully - with two web listeners on 9090 and 9091.

Comment: In the application's current state, I set the parent context after calling refresh() on the child context. It starts, but I cannot use autowire because the parent context is not set during startup of the child context. When you change the order (setParent() **before** refresh()) , or call createChildContext_failing(); instead of createChildContext_working(); in ChildContextConfig, the application won't start.

Comment: I updated the repository so that it will try to autowire a bean from the parent context (and fail doing so).

Comment: I've made a PR to your sample with suggested fix - https://github.com/thomashoell/SpringBootChildContext/pull/1

The problem is in that ChildContextConfig belongs to both parent and child contexts - AFAIU it should belong to child context only.
Also I moved refresh to after parent context set.

Comment: The child context isn't initialized, because the @ComponentScan of the main application excludes the child's package. You can do an @Import(ChildContextConfig.class) on ParentChildApplication.class, but then the child context tries to instanciate itself repeatedly during it's own initialization (no idea why, I excluded it from the child's own @ComponentScan). Regarding ChildContextConfig: AFAIU it should only belong to the parent context, since it just triggers the instanciation of the child, whose configuration is ChildContext.class. (see updated repo)

Comment: In some way, I got it to work (see repo). But I had to switch to the SpringApplicationBuilder approach. The main problem with the old approach was, that the child tried to bind to the parent's port, no matter what I tried, even if I hardcoded the port in ChildContextConfig. Even now I have to specify "--server.port" as argument to the child context

Comment: Update: the previous fix was broken, because I initialized the main context twice. It also wouldn't have worked anyway, because the web components must be contained within the child context (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-fluent-builder-api). I switched back to the old approach and annoteted my child bean's constructors with @Lazy. Works, but somewhat dirty in my opinion.